# error while inserting into linked table order_services

Tags: php, laravel

```
ErrorException
Undefined index: service_id in line:
```

$order->services()->attach([$serviceOrders['service'] =>

I Creat an application that has an order
the order_services table is a pivot table of orders and services I dont know from whare I take the index service ID
and how can I fix this issue??

here is the code:

**Order Controller**

```
$order= Order::create($data);

    $services[] =  $request->serviceOrders;

    if ($request->serviceOrders) {

        foreach ($services as $serviceOrders) {


            $order->services()->attach([$serviceOrders['service_id'] =>
                ['amount' => 
              $serviceOrders['amount'],'quantity'=>$serviceOrders['quantity']]]);
```

Cheking the requests:

```
    dd($request)

    "process" => "3"
          "serviceOrders" => array:2 [▼
            9 => array:3 [▼
              "service_id" => "2"
              "quantity" => "700"
              "amount" => "5"
            ]

The order services Table:

    test.blade.php

 <template x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
        <tr class="bg-white border-b-2 border-gray-200" >
            <td x-text="index + 1"></td>

            <td class="px-2 py-2">
                <input type="hidden"   />
                <select type="text"  x-model="field.service_id"
                        x-bind:name="`serviceOrders[${field.id}][service_id]`"
                               
                        class="input text-center ml-2 px-8 font-semibold">
                    @foreach(\App\Models\Service::all() as $service)
                        <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </td>
    <td class="px-2 py-2">
                <input  type="text"
               
                                x-model="field.quantity"
                        x-bind:name="`serviceOrders[${field.id}][quantity]`"
    
                        class="input">
            </td>
            <td class="px-2 py-2">
                <input x-model="field.amount" type="number"
                       x-bind:name="`serviceOrders[${field.id}][amount]`"
                       class="input">
            </td>
            <td class="px-2 py-2">
```

Can any one help?

Comment: That's a very minimal error message. No file name, no line number? Anyway, you use `service_id` twice as an index in an array, so it is probably one of those.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you for respond, please check the last edit